# Is it possible to change the query dynamically in grafana as user clicks on a dropdown value

Tags: grafana

Is there any way to change the grafana query on the basis of value selected in grafana dropdown.

Assume that there is a **dropdown in grafana dashboard** which has values **query1** and **query2**.

**Note:** Have used MySQL as database

If user selects **query1** then query to be executed is:

```
select time, val1
from temperature
where temp = 10;
```

If user selects **query2** then query to be executed is:

```
select time, humid
from humidity
where humidity = 50;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/mysql/

> Another option is a query that can create a key/value variable. The query should return two columns that are named __text and __value. The __text column value should be unique (if it is not unique then the first value is used). The options in the dropdown will have a text and value that allows you to have a friendly name as text and an id as the value.

So create dashboard variable with MySQL query (simple string selects with unions) which returns `__text` column (e.g. `query1`) / `__value` column (e.g. SQL `select time, val1 from temperature where temp = 10`) and use raw value of that variable in the  query editor (e.g. `${myvariable:raw}`. You may need a few attempts to have everything properly escaped and generated, but it is possible.

Comment: Your answer was helpful for me.